# MERN: whats another approach to store temporary data?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, react-redux

I'm building a multi-step form with basic info strings, and it has an image(s) upload mechanism.

Before I push the data to my DB, I think, I need to temporarily store data until the user reaches the last step and submits the form - to push it to my DB.

I think I need to put in place some type of local storage? Or is there another way to approach this?

Could anyone please guide me?
I'd appreciate it. Thank you for reading.

**edit:**
It's a component, not a single-page app. The data is not large. Sorry for not mentioning this earlier.

Comment: I presume this is a single page app, and that you are talking about storing the data in the browser here? Because if so, you should simply be keeping those values in memory (redux). Or do I misunderstand?

Comment: If the data is not large, then you can keep it in memory, either in the web page (if a single page app) or you can keep in an express-session object on the server.  Then, when done accumulating and everything is ready, you just write the whole thing to the DB.

Comment: @seesharper I tried a redux approach but I abandoned it because I wasn’t sure if I would be able to call data from step 1 when the user reaches step 2 (for example). And do you think that is possible with redux? If so, please tell me how would you approach it? thank you!

Comment: @jfriend00 thank you. I'm going to try this approach, and I will let you know.

Comment: @PopoTan yes of course you can access it at any point. Redux provides a global context or state object into which you can put whatever data you need, and it is designed for exactly this type of purpose. But I can't tell you how to implement it - you need to understand redux. Of course if your second step is on a different web page from step 1 (it should not be!), then you would need local storage. Otherwise, don't use it.

Comment: @seesharper That's great and very helpful. I'm very excited to learn more about redux. Thank you for taking the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 options to store data in browser as temporary.

1. LocalStorage (Max limit around 5 MB).
2. SessionStorage (Max limit around 5 MB).

LocalStorage is always available till you manually clear it.
SessionStorage will clear by itself on browser close.

So based on your need you can pick it from one of this.

Comment: Thank you for this overview.

Comment: If it solves your problem then Please accept this answer.